# Why does cout.precision() increase floating-point's precision?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, cout

I understand that single floating-point numbers have the precision of about 6 digits, so it's not surprising that the following program will output `2`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    //cout.precision(7);

    float f = 1.999998; //this number gets rounded up to the nearest hundred thousandths
    cout << f << endl;  //so f should equal 2

    return 0;
}
```

But when `cout.precision(7)` is included, in fact anywhere before `cout << f << endl;`, the program outputs the whole `1.999998`. This could only mean that `f` stored the whole floating-point number without rounding, right?

I know that `cout.precision()` should not, in any way, affect floating-point storage. Is there an explanation for this behavior? Or is it just on my machine?

Comment: That means that your _decimal_ number is stored as a closest _binary_ number. http://www.exploringbinary.com/7-bits-are-not-enough-for-2-digit-accuracy/

Comment: Floating-point values are stored in *binary*. It's a bit misleading to attach a decimal precision to them. The actual value stored in this case (making the fairly safe, but not guaranteed, assumptions of IEEE 754 binary32 format for `float` and round-to-nearest rounding for string-to-float conversions) is `1.99999797344207763671875`. Formatting that to 7 significant digits gives `1.999998`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ok so after re-reading your comment multiple times, I finally understood what it meant. While I appreciate the others hinting that it had something to do with floating-point storage/binary stuff, yours went straight to the point on what `f` really contained under the hood, making it sensible as to why the output is the way it is. I would mark your comment as the answer if only I could. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that single floating-point numbers have the precision of about 6 digits

*About* six decimal digits, or exactly 23 binary digits.

> this number gets rounded up to the nearest hundred thousand

No it doesn't. It gets rounded to the nearest 23 binary digits. Not the same thing, and not commensurable with it.

> Why does `cout.precision()` increase floating-point's precision?

It doesn't. It affects how it is *printed.*

Comment: "Exactly 23 bits" would be a non-denormal IEEE float. That's not actually guaranteed. I don't even think _bits_ are guaranteed; IIRC IBM still uses nibbles. (As in, the point still floats, but with 4 bit granularity).

Comment: Nitpick: IEEE 754 binary32 floats have a precision of 24 bits, not 23.

Answer (score 0):

As already written in the comments: The number is stored in binary.

`cout.setprecision()` actually does *not* affect the storage of the floating point value, it affects only the output precision.

Answer (score 0):

The default precision for std::cout is 6 according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) and your number is 7 digits long including the parts before and after the decimal place. Therefore when you set precision to 7, there is enough precision to represent your number but when you don't set the precision, rounding is performed.

Remember this only affects how the numbers are **displayed**, not how they are stored. Investigate IEEE floating point if you are interested in learning how floating point numbers are stored.

Try changing the number before the decimal place to see how it affects the rounding e.g `float f = 10.9998` and `float f = 10.99998`

Comment: On your second sentence, I know that setting precision to 7 is enough to display the number `1.9999998`. But in the statement `f = 1.999998`, f should contain `2` since it gets rounded, regardless on whether `cout::precision()` is set to any value. So by the time `cout << f` is excecuted, the output should be 2 (again, regardless on whether `cout::precision()` is set to any number).

Comment: @Christian: Read the various comments. Yes, it will be rounded, but it's rounded to `1.99999797344207763671875`.

Comment: You're still working on the assumption that floating point stores a specific number of **decimal** digits after the decimal point which is an oversimplification. Internally the number is stored in **binary** form according to the IEEE single floating point standard.